# heaven's gate with FASM (cannot make a call into the 64bits code)

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, 32bit-64bit, fasm

I am trying to implement the [heaven's gate](http://rce.co/knockin-on-heavens-gate-dynamic-processor-mode-switching/) in FASM. That means I want to execute 64 bits code into a 32 bits program.

You can see my code below:

```
format PE GUI 4.0
entry start

include 'C:\fasm\INCLUDE\win32ax.inc'

section '.rdata' data readable writeable
    test64_other     db "test64_other", 0

section '.idata' import data readable ; writeable
    library kernel32, 'KERNEL32.DLL',\
            user32, 'USER32.DLL'

    import kernel32,    ExitProcess, 'ExitProcess'

    import user32,      MessageBoxW, 'MessageBoxW'

section '.code' code readable executable
start:

     call       $33:bits64
     push       0
     push       eax
     push       eax
     push       0
     call       [MessageBoxW]

     call       $33:bits64_other    

exit:
    invoke      ExitProcess, 0

proc bits64
    use64
        call        @f
        du          'test64',0
@@:                     
        pop         rax 

    use32
        retf
endp

proc bits64_other
    use64
        xor         rcx, rcx
        lea         rdx, [test64_other]
        lea         r8, [test64_other]
        xor         r9, r9
        call        [MessageBoxW]

    use32
        retf
endp
```

The first MessageBox (**call      [MessageBoxW]**) works well, but the other into the **proc bits64_other** doesn't work. 
**The code even not compile anymore when i have the call into this procedure!!**

I am probably wrong somewhere. If you have a super great idea, could you help me figure it out?

Comment: Why `use32` before `retf`?  The `retf` will still execute in 64-bit mode.  (That's probably not the problem, though.)  What error message do you get with this?  [mcve]

Comment: Making library / system calls is unlikely to work well / correctly while running 64-bit code inside a process that started as 32-bit.  Maybe if you can dynamically load the 64-bit version of the same DLL as well, and call the 64-bit version of a library function?  Have you tried just using 64-bit code to do something you couldn't do in 32-bit mode, like efficiently do 64-bit math?  Or take advantage of all 16 integer and/or XMM registers?  That seems like a more sensible use-case for this.

Comment: I can use registers like r8, r9 and then move these values in a 32bits register like ecx. So i guess it works. But i cannot make a call ! :( Maybe i import badly m'y x64 fonctions ...